# How to catch http.get (SocketException)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter & Dart, trying to complete my first app.

I can't catch (with try-catch block) http.get SocketException (which happens when you call API and WiFi turned off)

I tried everything on the internet without luck, I even tried (Dio) package to catch this exception, but no success.

**How to reproduce:** use bottom code...turn off phone's WiFi...call API...now the app crashes with (SocketException) in your IDE.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VfD5.jpg

here is my simple code (updated)

```
     RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Call API"),
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  http.Response response = await getLoginResponse();
                  //do something with response
                  print(response.body);
                } catch (e) {
                  print("Button onPressed Error: " + e.toString());
                }
              },
            )
//---------------------------------------------------------------
Future<http.Response> getLoginResponse() {
    return http.get(loginUrl).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10))
    .then((response) {
      return response;
    }, onError: (e) {
      print("onError: " + e.toString());
    }).catchError((err) {
      print("catchError: " + err.toString());
      return null;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch several types of errors and handle each one separately

Example:

```
import 'dart:io' as Io;

http.Client client = http.Client();

try {
  response = await client.get(url).timeout(new Duration(seconds: 10));
} on Io.SocketException catch (_) {
  throw Exception('Not connected. Failed to load data');
} on TimeoutException catch (_) {
  throw Exception('Not connected. TimeOut Exception');
} catch (e) {
  // Default error handling;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get catch in RaisedButton's try-catch block, instead of return null in getLoginInfo() methods, you must return an Exception like this:

```
 Future<List<LoginObject>> getLoginInfo() async {
    try {
      List<LoginObject> loginObjectList = List<LoginObject>();
      http.Response loginResponse =
          await http.get(loginUrl).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
      if (loginResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        loginObjectList = loginObjectFromJson(loginResponse.body);
        return loginObjectList;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Authentication Error');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: " + e.toString());
      return throw Exception('Connection Error');;
    }
  }
```

**Note:** If you want to handle each one of error response, you can create an custom ErrorModelClass and handle error state with it and finally return your ErrorModelClass.

```
 catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error is HttpResponseError ? error : HttpResponseError(0,"error connection");
```

**HttpResponseError** is my custom model class.

Comment: I just want to handle this exception, cause no (try-catch block) in the code above can handle that exception. when this exception happens the app crashes, although http.get surrounded by try-catch block.

Comment: @Vamp808 ok, got it. I test your code. http.get() doesn't have any exception. check two things. first check **LoginObject** with your API response after that check this line: loginObjectList = loginObjectFromJson(loginResponse.body);

Comment: thank you for reply, the exception is from http.get , to make things more clear please see my update.

Comment: @Vamp808 I used Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA), the try-catch block caught the exception. This problem did not occur to me.

Comment: thank you so much, I tried debugging the app with Android Studio and this problem did not happen, the try-catch block caught the SocketException and the app did not crash.
It's look like this is related with how VS Code and/or Flutter/Dart plugins works (maybe a bug).